# Setup CRON to automatically flag a recently added product into the "New Product" category

Tags: php, magento, cron, magento-1.7

I had created a "New Product" category in Magento, and I'm trying to get a CRON Job to run and automatically flag products that have been created in the past 14 days, and remove them from the "New Product" category once it's been created for more than 14 days.

I looked at a couple posts, and they mentioned an article referred to here: http://www.ecomdev.org/2010/06/07/how-to-schedule-the-future-product-activation.html The only problem is that the post is no longer valid. Google cache didn't store it either.

Answer (score 0):

Hello please try as follows :

First create a custom module, and in config.xml file copy following code:

```
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <inchoo_birthday_send>
            <schedule><cron_expr>0 1 * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
            <run><model>birthday/observer::sendBirthayEmail</model></run>
        </inchoo_birthday_send>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

create a model file named observer.php (in model folder) with method sendBirthayEmail as follows:

```
class Inchoo_Birthday_Model_Observer
{
    public function sendBirthayEmail()
    {
        $day = new DateTime();
        $todayDate  = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',1); //only enabled product

        $day->modify( "-14 days" );
        $fromDate = $day->format("Y-m-d 00:00:00");
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('or'=> array( 0 => array('date' => true, 'from' => $fromDate), 1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))), 'left');
        $collection->setOrder('created_at', 'desc');
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*'); //add product attribute to be fetched
        $collection->addStoreFilter();   
        if(!empty($collection))
        {
            //do your work here.
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Please not that i have copied above code from one of my installation and not 100% complete, you have to tweak into the code to make it in your desired output.